# Найти все согласные буквы которые входят только в одно слово

Tags: c++, строки, vector, set, multiset

В общем у меня есть std::vector строк,в нем мне нужно найти согласные буквы которые входят только в одно слово,не могу понять как решить такое задание пробую через std::set и std::multiset и ничего не получаеться,помогите пожалуйста

Так же уточнение что буквы латинские,допустим есть строки "aaaa" "iia"
В результате должно выводиться только 'i' так как буква 'а' входит в два слова

У меня получилось только сделать чтобы вывести согласные буквы которые повторяються один раз в тексте,но может быть случай когда согласная буква будет несколько раз в одном слове,но больше не будет повторяться в строке и в таком случае мой вариант не работает.

Comment: Что такое «слово»? Как оно представлено в твоём коде?

Comment: Вообще сначало была строка но потом я ее разбил на слова и поместил в вектор

Comment: Тоесть изначальная строка допустим "aaaaa,bbb,bb,b" у меня получился вектор {"aaaaa","bbb","bb","b"}

Comment: Теперь мне нужно найти согласную букву,которая попадает только в одно слово

Comment: Символы из каждого слова собираешь в set, потом всё из set считаешь в общий словарь, чистишь/пересоздаёшь set.

Comment: Очищать перед тем как перехожу к следующему елементу вектора?

Comment: К следующему слову. Если у тебя вектор слов, то да.

Comment: Да но тут все же проблема в том что мне нужно знать откуда конечные согласные буквы из одного слова или из разных,возможно я просто не до конца понял ваш вариант решения

Comment: По итогу у тебя в руках останется std::map<string, int> (unordered, скорее всего), в котором ты всё посчитал. Проходишься, и те, где ровно 1 выводишь.

Comment: Вот как раз проблема в том что нужно обойтись без map

Comment: Не вижу ограничений про словарь в вопросе. Используй 21 переменную))

Comment: "Проходишься, и те, где ровно 1 выводишь" почему 1? Одинаковых согласных букв может быть несколько если они в одном слове,если буква такая одна во всем тексте то выводить,если одинаковых согласных букв в тексте много но они все в одном слове то тоже на вывод

Comment: Или 3 множества: A - «буквы в слове», B - «буквы встретившиеся хотя бы в одном слове», C - «буквы встретившиеся более, чем в одном слове». Результат — set_difference(B, C)

Comment: почему 1? Потому что в счётчике ты считаешь, только по заполненному множеству, в котором нет дубликатов букв в слове.

Comment: Можете предложить вариант кода? У меня не получаеться

Comment: Вообщето ваш пример непонятен. Сначала вы говорите про согласные, а потом приводите гласные.

Answer (score 1):

Создаете массив, в котором для каждой согласной буквы храните количество слов, в которых она встречалась, назовем его `wordsCount`. Далее для каждого слова:

- сортируете буквы
- убираете дупликаты
- убираете гласные

Теперь для каждой оставшейся буквы увеличиваете счетчик в `wordsCount`.

В конце в `wordsCount` ищете елемент со значением 1 - индекс это нужная буква.

Примерно может выглядеть вот так:

```
int wordsCount[26] = {};

std::vector<std::string> words;
// наполнение массива words
for( auto &word : words ) {
   auto beg = word.begin();
   auto end = word.end();
   std::sort( beg, end );
   end = std::unique( beg, end ); // удаляем дупликаты
   end = std::remove_if( beg, end, []( char c ) { // удалем гласные
      return c == 'a' or c == 'e' or c == 'i' or c == 'o'
             or c == 'u' or c == 'y';
   } );
   for( auto it = beg; it != end; ++it ) 
       wordsCount[*it-'a']++;
}
```

Поиск элемента со значением 1 я оставлю для автора.

Answer (score 0):

symBig - Алфивит с большими буквами

symSmall - Алфавит с маленькими буквами

str - Вводимое сообщение

Проходим циклом по сообщению и по-буквенно сравниваем

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string str, symBig = "BCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZ", symSmall = "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz";
    cin >> str;
    int count = 0;
    int d = 0;
    for (int i = 0;  i < symBig.length(); ++i) {
        for ( int j = 0; j < str.length(); ++j) {
            if (str[j] == symBig[i] || str[j] == symSmall[i]) count++;
            if (count > 1) {
                count = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (count == 1) {
            cout << symSmall[i];
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).